# Finding values which make a determinant $0$ in an $8\times 8$ symmetric matrix.

Tags: matrices, determinant

> For each $a\in\mathbb{R}$, determine those values of $X\in\mathbb{R}$ for which the determinant of the following matrix is $0$.
> $$ \left(\begin{matrix}
> a & X & a & a & a & a & a & a \\
> X & a & a & a & a & a & a & a \\
> a & a & a & X & a & a & a & a \\
> a & a & X & a & a & a & a & a \\
> a & a & a & a & a & X & a & a \\
> a & a & a & a & X & a & a & a \\
> a & a & a & a & a & a & a & X \\
> a & a & a & a & a & a & X & a \\
> \end{matrix}\right)$$

I am trying to find the values of $X$, and after using column switches I can get the main diagonal to be all $X$'s and $a$'s  on either side. Is there a neat way of answering this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: find the determinant in general for such $n\times n$-matrices with even $n$. For $n=8$ it is given by
$$
\det(A)=-(7a + X)(a - X)^7.
$$
Try $n=2,4,6$ for this. Then prove the general formula by induction.

Answer (score 0):

Let

- $A$ be your matrix.
- $\tau$ be the $8\times 8$ matrix with entries $\tau_{ij} = \begin{cases}1, & A_{ij} = X\\0, & A_{ij} = a\end{cases}$.
- $u$ be the $8\times 1$ column matrix with all entries $1$.

It is easy to see $\tau^{-1} = \tau$, $\det\tau = 1$ and $u^T \tau u = 8$.

Notice $A = (X-a)\tau + auu^T$ is a rank-1 update of the invertible matrix $B \stackrel{def}{=} (X-a)\tau$. You can evaluate its determinant using [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma).
$$\begin{align}\det(A) & = \det(B+ auu^T) = \det(B) (1 + au^TB^{-1}u)\\
&= (X-a)^8 \left(1 + \frac{a}{X-a}u^T \tau^{-1} u\right) = (X-a)^8\left(1 + \frac{8a}{X-a}\right)\\
&= (X-a)^7(X + 7a)\end{align}$$